# Navbar shrinks, content change on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-transitions

How can I achieve a scrolling effect where the navbar shrinks and an image transitions to words on scroll, as seen on: http://www.sarahlichang.com/?

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(document).scrollTop() > 150) {
        $('.navbar').addClass('shrink');
    }
    else {
        $('.navbar').removeClass('shrink');
    }
});
```

Comment: You already have the jQuery code to do this. The link you provided doesn't transition an image to words. They are both images included on the page. You could do this a couple different ways: use jQuery to transition both images to display/hide when the user scrolls to a certain point or use jQuery to add/remove CSS classes to each image

Comment: I'd test if the class is already applied as well in your if/then before invoking addClass()/removeClass()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make it look that way you'll need to use some kind of animation, a css transition does the trick.

```
-webkit-transition:all 0.2s ease;
transition: all 0.2s ease;
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gkrtk8s3/)

Comment: @Joe this is what you're looking for. Now you just will need to switch between the two images you want to show. Or have some fancy text underneath the image and just hide the image.. developers preference.

Comment: @Joe Yea you could either use a background-image, or you could insert it dynamically using JS. World's your oyster.